# Text select in Vaadin TextField on IE

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Double-click on my Vaadin table cell makes it editable.
I understand that once it's editable it's a TextField.
I'm able to select text in the TextField while on Chrome.
However, I'm unable to select the text on IE. 
I'm using IE11. Expectation for the page is to work same across all(IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox) browsers.

Vaadin 7.4.3 is being used in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your Vaadin version and test. Probably this can be a bug and we can not help you. I suggest to create bug report on: https://dev.vaadin.com/